# Complex analysis analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I need to tell where $f(z)$ is analytic.$f(z)=(2x+y-x^2y)+i(3+2y-xy^2)$.  I found that the cauchy riemann eqns for $u_x=v_y$ but when comparing $-u_y$ and $v_x$ I get $-1+x^2=-y^2$

What does this tell me about the functions analytic behavior?

Thanks

Comment: it meant that your function will be analytic if it satisfies the second condition.It will be satisfied on this circle $x^2+y^2=1$ @Jim55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ if and only if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied for all $z \in \Omega$. In your case, you have $u_x=v_y$, but

$$\ \ \ \ -u_y=v_x \ \ \ \ \text{ if and only if } \ \ \ \ x^2+y^2=1$$

That is, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied only on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, there exists no region where $f$ is analytic. This means, for example, that $f$ is complex differentiable only on the unit circle, but does not have a power series expansion in any region of the complex plane.

Comment: So i would state that f(z) is analytic nowhere?

Comment: so i would state that f(z) is analytic nowhere?

Comment: That technically depends on the definition of analytic, so if you are using a book, you should check that. In my experience, analytic is defined to be equivalent to holomorphic, which means complex differentiable in a region (nonempty open connected subset) of $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, $f$ is indeed analytic nowhere.

Comment: So because the unit circle is a closed set that is why we cannot satisfy the nonempty open connected set criteria?

Comment: No. It's because the unit circle contains no open sets in $\mathbb{C}$. Think of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$. Open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must be 2-dimensional, but the unit circle is only 1-dimensional.

Comment: On the other hand, to see that closed sets are not the problem, suppose your function was complex differentiable (i.e. satisfied the Cauchy-Riemann equations) within the closed unit disc. You can then say that it is analytic in the closed unit disc, which would be defined to mean that it is analytic in every open subset of the closed unit disc.